# Tab ribbon disappears and font size increases when expanding/ collapsing an item in profile on mobile

Tags: bug, profile-page

In the "All actions" drop-down in the *Profile* > *Activity* area of the Stack Overflow profile on mobile, expanding/ collapsing an item causes the tab ribbon to disappear.

I'm using Safari 13.0.4 on iOS 13.3.

I checked other sites (i.e. Meta SO, Meta SE, and Super User to name a few) and they look correct.

When an item is expanded, the tabs go missing and the font size seems a bit too large relative to the title of the 'action' itself.

#### Stack Overflow

| Collapsed | Expanded |
| --- | --- |
| [image: All actions page on Stack Overflow profile, with no items expanded] | [image: All actions page on Stack Overflow profile, with one item expanded] |

#### Meta Stack Overflow

| Collapsed | Expanded |
| --- | --- |
| [image: All actions page on Meta Stack Overflow profile, with no items expanded] | [image: All actions page on Meta Stack Overflow profile, with one item expanded] |